# Specify the order that imported targets get run

Tags: nuget, target, csproj

I have a Nuget package that has targets that copy files to the bin directory, and these targets are imported with a auto generated import statement like this

```
<Import Project="..\packages\[some path].targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\[some path].targets')" />
```

I have some post build events that depend on those files, but I found that my post build events execute before the Nuget targets.

Is there a way to specify the order that imported targets get executed so that, for example, they could run before post build events?

Comment: did you rem it out and give it a shot?

Comment: @Jeb50 I'm not sure what you mean by rem it out. I am asking the question because I have tried it and in my build output I am seeing that the Nuget targets are getting run after my post build events. I've tried looking stuff up on MSDN, but I can't find anything on specifying run order of imported targets. You can specify run order of targets defined in your project using InitialTargets and DefaultTargets.